# How emerges a color "magnetic" (chromomagnetic) field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, quarks, color-charge

How does the color charge of quarks brings a "color magnetic (chromomagnetic) field" into existence? When the quark is moving you should expect that it causes a field just as a magnetic field arises around a moving electric charge.

I googled for "chromomagnetic field" but about the cause, I couldn't find anything. The field **does** exist though. For example the [chromomagnetic dipole](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00615) exists.

Comment: google chromoelectric, chromomagnetic

Answer (score 7):

We usually do not talk about a "color magnetic field" to begin with. The strong force is treated fully relativistically from its beginning.

If you want, you can define a "color electric field" and "color magnetic field" from the strong field strength tensor $G_{\mu\nu}^a$ in exact analogy to electromagnetism as $E^a_i := G_{0 i}^a$ and $B^a_i := \epsilon_{ijk}G_{jk}^a$ where then a Lorentz transformation turns them into each other exactly like in the EM case (and hence you might say that a "moving color electric field" creates a "color magnetic field"), but the usefulness of these quantities is doubtful.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder: Please do not make trivial edits to old posts. In the context of this question, electric and magnetic are fully interchangable and your edit does not improve my answer in any way in my eyes. Edits like this unnecessarily bump the question in the queue of active questions.

Comment: But I asked explicitly about a color magnetic field, not a color electric field. They may be interchangeable, but in your answer, you stated: **We usually do not talk about a "color electric field" to begin with.** In my eyes, it **does** improve your answer. This doesn't mean your answer is useful, though.